# Setting a Multicurrency field in Apex

Tags: multi-currency

I have a currency field on my Opportunity object, in a multicurrency enabled org, and I have a numerical field in a child object of it, which holds an "always" GBP financial value.

I then have a trigger which at a certain moment in time needs to copy the numerical field into the Opportunity..

When I do this, the raw numerical value is dumped into the Opportunity, and then displayed *as is* against the Opportunity Currency ISO code.

eg. The child has a numerical value of 600.50 - which is known asolutely to be GBP, but when this is copied into an Opportunity whose currency setting is USD, it shows something like

> 600.50 USD (390.53 GBP)

(ths GBP bit is because of my locale settings, users in other currencies will see even more random conversions)

So my question is **How do I indicate when I set a value into a multicurrency field that it is in fact in GBP - or - how do I determine what Curreny it is expecting, and convert my GBP value into it first?** (even though in the second scenario, the display is just going to covert it right back in the bit in the brackets!)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If an org has multicurrency enabled, the standard field CurrencyISOCode is available on every object. It will default to a user's default currency. You can set it to any of the enabled currencies for your org. Enabled currencies are found in Setup > Company Profile > Manage Currencies.

So if you have an always-GBP value, you need to check `Opportunity.CurrencyISOCode` and if it isn't GBP, find the exchange rate for your currency in the CurrencyType object and read its ConversionRate.

For example:

```
SELECT Id, ConversionRate 
FROM CurrencyType 
WHERE IsoCode = :Opportunity.CurrencyISOCode
```

If your org has Advanced Currency Management enabled, exchange rates are stored in the DatedConversionRate object, and have a validity date range. For example:

```
SELECT Id, ConversionRate
FROM DatedConversionRate
WHERE IsoCode = :Opportunity.CurrencyISOCode
AND   StartDate <= :Opportunity.CloseDate
AND   NextStartDate > :Opportunity.CloseDate
```

You can use any date you want to get the dated exchange rate, but as @crop1645 pointed out, the default that Salesforce uses for Opportunity Amount is CloseDate, so you would be consistent if you use CloseDate as well.

Comment: you might want to also add bits about if user is using Advanced Currency Mgt which has dated exchange rates - in these cases, the currency conversion logic depends on some date and uses SObject `DatedConversionRate`

Comment: Ok. Thank you guys. We are using the dated exchange stuff, so I will bear that in mind. Will feed back if I have success with this advice (probs tomorrow now)

Comment: @crop1645 good idea. done.

Comment: Dominic -- if using Opportunity, DCR by default in OOB SFDC will use `closeDate`, not `createdDate`

Comment: I thought it did too, but then when I typed it, it didn't feel right. I'll fix the answer.